# how to remove punctuation from list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, preprocessor, data-cleaning, scrape

can I any one help me with this code 
now I get 'test2' as same as 'test', if I test is string it works good but as list it not working properly

```
 punc = set(string.punctuation)
 test=[" course content good though textbook badly written.not got energy 
 though seems good union.it distance course i'm sure facilities.n/an/ain 
last year offer poor terms academic personal. seems un become overwhelmed trying become run"]

test2 = ''.join(w for w in test if w not in punc)
 print(test2)
```

I want to remove all punctuation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import string
test=[" course content good though textbook badly written.not got energy though seems good union.it distance course i'm sure facilities.n/an/ain last year offer poor terms academic personal. seems un become overwhelmed trying become run"]
test2 = ''.join(w for w in test[0] if w not in string.punctuation )
print(test2)
```

If there are multiple strings inside the list

```
import string
test=["Hi There!"," course content good though textbook badly written.not got energy though seems good union.it distance course i'm sure facilities.n/an/ain last year offer poor terms academic personal. seems un become overwhelmed trying become run"]
#if there are multiple string in the list
for x in test:
    print(''.join(w for w in x if w not in string.punctuation ))
# If there are multiple strings in the list and you want to join all of them togather
print(''.join(w for w in [x for x in test] if w not in string.punctuation ))
```

If you need to append it to a list variable

```
import string
test2=[]
test=["Hi There!"," course content good though textbook badly written.not got energy though seems good union.it distance course i'm sure facilities.n/an/ain last year offer poor terms academic personal. seems un become overwhelmed trying become run"]
#if there are multiple string in the list
for x in test:
    test2.append(''.join(w for w in x if w not in string.punctuation ))
print(test2)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question at all. He wanted to use a set. He even states that it works as a string.

Comment: @DWuest Where does he say he wants to use a set? All you can see is that he used a set. Not that he wants it using a set.

Comment: he says it doesn't work when using a list. He uses a set in his example code though.

Comment: @akrammalek This code should work fine. Comment if you are unable to solve it using this.

Comment: it works fine when you print it but when I want to append it to a variable it won't work

Comment: @akrammalek I have edited it so that you can remove the punctuation from all the strings in list and append it to a new list.

Answer (score 1):

Since test is a list, ‘for w in test’ will return the first item of the list, being the complete string. So you then need to access all the items of ‘w’ to actually test all individual characters of the string.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest (and arguably most Pythonic way of doing this) is using translate.

```
import string
test=["Hi There!"," course content good though textbook badly written.not got energy though seems good union.it distance course i'm sure facilities.n/an/ain last year offer poor terms academic personal. seems un become overwhelmed trying become run"]

# Create a translate table that translates all punctuation to nothing
transtable = {ord(a):None for a in string.punctuation}

# Apply the translation to all strings in the list
[s.translate(transtable) for s in test]
```